# delete data in datagridview and database through contextmenustrip

Tags: c#, datagridview

May I ask some help?
I am using contextmenustrip in my datagridview and it has a delete button on it. I want to delete the data in datagridview as well as in the database. How can I do that? I'm using visual studio 2010

Thank you :)

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        conn.Open();

        //Thinking that the first cell in every row contains the primary key, it will get the primary key from the first selected row
        string key = dgvCustomer.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Delete * from customerTable WHERE custNo = '" + key + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Get the index of the selected row and delete it from the rows
        int indexOfSelectedRow = dgvCustomer.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        dgvCustomer.Rows.RemoveAt(indexOfSelectedRow);

    }
```

Comment: Use a DataTable.  Make the DataTable the data source of the DGV.  The rows and columns index of the DGV and DataTable are the same.  So when a row is deleted from the DGV delete the same row from the datatable.  You can fill the DataTable using an adapter from the database.  Then after deleting data from the datatable you can use the datatable accept updates method which which will change the values in the database automatically.

Comment: What is in the DataGridView? is it the result of joining multiple tables? Or is it the data from a single database table? Or is it a view in a database? Need to know what the data represents in your DataGridView

Comment: @Robertcode the data is from a single database table.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you achieve the result indicated in your question.

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string");
    conn.Open();

    //Thinking that the first cell in every row contains the primary key, it will get the primary key from the first selected row
    string key = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from YourTableName where id = " + key, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Get the index of the selected row and delete it from the rows
    int indexOfSelectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(indexOfSelectedRow);
}
```

Comment: I got an error. It says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from customerTable where custNo = 0000013' at line 1"

Comment: I'm  sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Post your code related to database connection and manipulation, there might be some problem there.